# JDBC - How do I accumulate data from ResultSet

Tags: jdbc

How would I accumulate data from a ResultSet? What I'm trying to do is get the price from the ResultSet and it only gets the first value, but what I want is every price for e.g 25.0, 10.00, and 15.00 I have stored them in a Double datatype, but the Result Set only gets the last value when I have a **while(rs.next()** and if I have **if(rs.next())** it will get 25.00 but I want all the prices to be added. How would I do this exactly? Thanks!

```
if(rs2.next()) {

           jTextArea3.append("\n");
           jTextArea3.append("\n");
           jTextArea3.append("Part Type: " + rs2.getString("PartType"));
           jTextArea3.append("\n");
           jTextArea3.append("Description: " + rs2.getString("Description"));
           jTextArea3.append("\n");
           jTextArea3.append("Price: " + rs2.getString("Price"));
           partsCost = rs2.getDouble("Price");
           System.out.println(partsCost);
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this is what you mean?

```
double total = 0;

while(rs.next()) {

           jTextArea3.append("\n");
           jTextArea3.append("\n");
           jTextArea3.append("Part Type: " + rs2.getString("PartType"));
           jTextArea3.append("\n");
           jTextArea3.append("Description: " + rs2.getString("Description"));
           jTextArea3.append("\n");
           jTextArea3.append("Price: " + rs2.getString("Price"));
           partsCost = rs2.getDouble("Price");
           System.out.println(partsCost);

           total += partsCost;

      }  

System.out.println(total);
```

You don't show the SQL query.  If you only care about the total of partsCosts, and not the other details, you would need to change your query to have an aggregate function such as, "select sum(partsCost)... "